# How to check if a EditText field has change content under runtime in Android

Tags: java, android

How can I check if two `EditTextField`'s have changed content under runtime in android? I want to enable a button if both `EditTextField`'s have some content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EditText` is a subclass of `TextView`, which has the method you're looking for, [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29).